# Azure Streaming Analytics Query Pivot table without aggregation

Tags: azure

I have the following json input from EventHub:

```
{"MeasurementReading":
[{"TimeStamp":"2017-02-23T07:08:49","Tag":"Tag1","Value":"1","Good":"true","Questionable":"false","Substituted":"false"},
{"TimeStamp":"2017-02-23T07:08:49","Tag":"Tag2","UnitsAbbreviation":"","Value":"2","Good":"true","Questionable":"false","Substituted":"false"},
{"TimeStamp":"2017-02-23T07:08:49","Tag":"Tag3","UnitsAbbreviation":"","Value":"3","Good":"true","Questionable":"false","Substituted":"false"},
{"TimeStamp":"2017-02-23T07:08:49","Tag":"Tag4","UnitsAbbreviation":"","Value":"4","Good":"true","Questionable":"false","Substituted":"false"},
{"TimeStamp":"2017-02-23T07:08:49","Tag":"Tag5","UnitsAbbreviation":"","Value":"5","Good":"true","Questionable":"false","Substituted":"false"},
{"TimeStamp":"2017-02-23T07:08:49","Tag":"Tag6","UnitsAbbreviation":"","Value":"6","Good":"true","Questionable":"false","Substituted":"false"}]}
```

I would like write a query within the Streaming Analytic that would pivot the table that would produce the following table:

> TimeStamp,            Tag1,    Tag2,  Tag3,   Tag4, Tag5,    Tag6
>
> "2017-02-23T07:08:49",1       ,2,     3,      4,    5,       6

I have tried to solves this for a day no with no luck, I would appreciated any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps write a JavaScript function that will do this transformation

Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions